# Method to read data from a file when plot histogram with python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I ‘ve written a function to plot the histogram for an 1-D array theta . But one thing I do not like in this function is that the data  is in the code. Could you know how to keep the data in  a *file* and to make the function *read* them from the file?  Since the data is usually much larger.

PS: The code is

```
#hist.py
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta=[77.438110,82.811340,59.701530,124.94859,82.991272,84.300468,24.639610,112.28130]
num_bins = 72
# the histogram of the data 
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(theta, num_bins, range=[0,180], normed = True,  histtype='bar',facecolor='green')
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$($\degree$)')
plt.ylabel(r'$P(\theta)$')
plt.show()
```

Comment: what do you mean by reading the data from the histogram? You already have it in variables `n` and `bins`...

Comment: @jiadong, where dies the data come from?

Comment: @SaulloCastro If the array theta includes larger number of entries,eg., 10000, it is not good to define it in this way  `theta=[77.438110,...,112.28130]`. I keep the elements of theta in another file, and then I want to find  how to read the data from the file.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It is in a one column file named theta.dat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each  data entry is on separate lines in your theta.dat file and theta.dat  is your current working directory.

```
theta=[]
with open("theta.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        theta.append(float(line))
print theta
[77.43811, 82.81134, 59.70153, 124.94859, 82.991272, 84.300468, 24.63961, 112.2813]
```

just run your code as you have, I have put in the print statement just to show you how the data structure looks.

```
num_bins = 72
# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(theta, num_bins, range=[0,180], normed = True,        histtype='bar',facecolor='green')
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$($\degree$)')
plt.ylabel(r'$P(\theta)$')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. I see what you mean. Another thing should change is replace the "theta.dat" by its path. So I hope this is clear enough for others.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a txt file with the separated-comma theta values in the first line and the number of bins in the second line:

```
77.438110,82.811340,59.701530,124.94859,82.991272,84.300468,24.639610,112.28130
72
```

You can add this:

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

def read(file_name):
    f = open(file_name,'r')
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    theta = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data[0]), delimiter=",")
    num_bins = data[1]
    return theta, num_bins
```

Example:

```
theta, num_bins = read("data_file.txt")
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(theta, num_bins, range=[0,180], normed = True,      histtype='bar',facecolor='green')
plt.xlabel(r'$\theta$($\degree$)')
plt.ylabel(r'$P(\theta)$')
plt.show()
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html